# printing the same index of two different lists in python

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have an enormous string and I've created a list of all the matching patterns in that string called 'found'. I've also created a list of all the locations of said patterns called 'locations'. Now I want to print the pattern found and its corresponding location all in one line, separated by a tab, but i'm getting tripped up on the loops. Here's my latest attempt:

```
for i in found:
    print i + '\t' + locations['i']
```

but I obviously get an error. I can get it to print the locations or the patterns or one then the other, but i'm not quite sure how to get them all on the same line.

edit: the variables are found = a list of strings (patterns found in the overall string) and locations = a list of the locations of said patterns found using re.finditer

eitehr way, zip() worked perfectly for my needs.  thanks.

Comment: post the `location` and `found` list in the question, so that the question can become more clear.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: +1 @ your comment. We need to know the structure of `found` and `location` in order to be of any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `zip()`:

```
for i,j in zip(found,locations):
    print "\t".join((i,str(j)))
```

Comment: success!  thank you.  just so i understand, zip is returning a tuple that just returns the same spot in two separate lists?

Comment: yes,you got it right. read more about [zip()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip)

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the list via its index, you need to pass an integer; `'i'` is a character, not the integer you expect to find in `i`. So do:

```
for i in found:
    print i + '\t' + locations[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `enumerate()` is what you are looking for:

```
for i, pattern in enumerate(found):
    print pattern + '\t' + locations[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

You code assumes there is only one match. To find and print all matches it is efficient to use the `re` module.

```
import re

patterns = ['test', 'is', 'a', 'jest']
txt = 'This test is just a test, not a jest'

for p in patterns:
    pos =  [m.start() for m in re.finditer(p, txt)]
    if len(pos):
        print '\t'.join((p, str(pos)))
```

This prints:

```
test    [5, 20]
is      [2, 10]
a       [18, 30]
jest    [32]
```